# Spring Bean creation from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am using a @Configuration to configure the creation of a RestTemplate bean, that needs some information such as API-key and host etc.

The thing is, I need to be able to make a number of beans, matching a number of API-keys, fetched from a database.

My code right now, looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DandomainProperties {
    private String apiKey;
    private String host;
    private String ordersPath;
    private String orderPath;
    private String manufacturerPath;
    private DanDomainRestTemplate danDomainRestTemplate;


@Bean
DanDomainRestTemplate danDomainRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
            .basicAuthentication("", this.apiKey)
            .build(DanDomainRestTemplate.class);
}
```

So basically, I need to change the configuration and then create a matching RestTemplate bean, any number of times.

Comment: mark bean creator method `@Scope("prototype")` and re-read configuration from DB each time a bean is requested

Answer (score 0):

As far I as know from your question, you want to create a restTemplate for each individual situation, maybe you could replace an @Configuration bean provider with a Service that provides different kinds of apis?

For example:

```
@Service
public class DandomainApiProvider {
    @Autowired
    private ApiRepository apiRepository;
    @Autowired
    private DanDomainRestTemplate danDomainRestTemplate;


DanDomainRestTemplate restTemplateOf(String queryId) {
    // Fetch apikeys from DB by repository
    String apiKey = apiRepository.queryApiKey(queryId);
    return restTemplateBuilder
            .basicAuthentication("", apiKey)
            .build(DanDomainRestTemplate.class);
}
```

With DanDomainRestTemplate your own implementation, and ApiRepository some definition like:

```
public interfadce ApiRepository {
    // Query apiKey by ID
    String queryApiKey(String queryId);
}
```